# Hook @beforeSave no funciona

Tags: adonisjs, adonis-5

estoy desarrollando una aplicación con AdonisJs en TypeScript, y estoy teniendo problemas para hacer funcionar el método (hook) `@beforeSave` para hashear la contraseña del usuario antes de guardarla en la base de datos. Leí en la documentación pero no pude encontrar el error. Si alguien sabe como solucionarlo se lo agradecería mucho. Por cierto, intenté hashear la contraseña de forma "manual" pero al ser typescript es bastante estricto con los tipos de variables y no me lo permite. Muchas gracias!

Mi modelo UserAuth.ts:

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon'
import Hash from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Hash'
import {
  column,
  beforeSave,
  BaseModel,
} from '@ioc:Adonis/Lucid/Orm'

export default class UserAuth extends BaseModel {
  
  public static table = "api_auth"
  @column({ isPrimary: true })
  public id: number

  @column()
  public id_empresa: number

  @column()
  public usuario: string
  
  @column({ serializeAs: null })
  public contrasena: string

  @column()
  public nombre: string

  @column()
  public apellido: string

  @column()
  public telefono: string

  @column()
  public email: string

  @column()
  public recordar_logueado?: boolean

  @column()
  public activo: boolean

  @column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true })
  public creado: DateTime

  @column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true, autoUpdate: true })
  public ultimo_login: DateTime

  @column()
  public estado: boolean

  @beforeSave()
  public static async hashPassword (userAuth: UserAuth) {
    if (userAuth.$dirty.password) {
      userAuth.contrasena = await Hash.make(userAuth.contrasena)
    }
  }
}
```

Mi controlador:

```
async crear_usuario({request}){
        try{
            let { usuario, contrasena, email } = request.all()
            const user = await UserAuth.create({
                usuario: usuario,
                contrasena: contrasena,
                email: email
            })
            return user
        }catch(error){
            return error
        }
    }
```

Comment: @BetaM disculpa, me falto de corregir un par de cosas cuando lo publique, ahora si está bien

Comment: Me da verguenza haber preguntado esto y no haberme percatado, gracias @BetaM!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El [hook **`beforeSave`**](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/models/hooks) te permite trabajar sobre la instancia del modelo en donde fue definido.

Dicho lo anterior, es importante notar que además [el objeto **`$dirty`**](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/models/hooks#understanding-the-dirty-property) te da acceso a las propiedades modificadas de dicha instancia, luego entonces esas propiedades son las definidas en la misma clase.

Finalmente entonces solo debes cambiar esto:

```
if (userAuth.$dirty.password) {
```

Por esto otro:

```
if (userAuth.$dirty.contrasena) {
```

Pues password no existe en *`AuthUser`*.